# Suppressing stack trace dump in Laravel log after App::abort(403)

Tags: php, laravel-4, stack-trace, abort

I'm setting up a custom Acl for a Laravel 4.1 application.

My Routes.php file applies a before filter:

```
// Global authenticator
Route::filter('auth.vle', function()
{
    return (new vleAuth)->authenticate();
});
// Authenticate all requests, except those to /login, /logout and /forgottenpassword
Route::whenRegex('/^(?!login|logout)(.*)$/', 'auth.vle');
```

and my vleAuth authenticate() method:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->acl = new vleAclService();
    $endpoint = Route::current()->getAction()['controller'];
    if (!$this->acl->validateEndpoint($endpoint)) {
        Log::info('Routing', array( Route::current()->getUri(), $endpoint));
        App::abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
}
```

When I access an endpoint which I am privileged to access, no problems; and when I access an endpoint that I'm not privileged to access, then I get a `Forbidden - We're really sorry but you don't have the necessary permissions to access this page.` message, so the authentication is working correctly as far as the "front-end" is concerned, and the routing information in the log bears this out.

However, whenever I try to access an endpoint that I'm not authenticated for, I also get a stack trace dumped in the Laravel log

```
[2014-06-12 15:00:16] production.INFO: ROUTE VALIDATION ["View_Reviews_ReviewsController@getIndex",false] []
[2014-06-12 15:00:16] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException' with message 'Unauthorized action.' in /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:875
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(211): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->abort(403, 'Unauthorized ac...')
#1 /srv/api/laravel/app/controllers/vleAuth.php(104): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('abort', Array)
#2 /srv/api/laravel/app/controllers/vleAuth.php(104): Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::abort(403, 'Unauthorized ac...')
#3 /srv/api/laravel/app/routes.php(20): vleAuth->authenticate()
#4 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(154): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('router.filter: ...', Array, true)
#7 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1399): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->until('router.filter: ...', Array)
#8 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1262): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callRouteFilter('auth.vle', Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callPatternFilters(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callRouteBefore(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(968): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(738): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/FrameGuard.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#19 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(606): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/vagrant/vleAppV2/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#21 {main} [] []
```

I'm trying to suppress this because I don't want the logs filling up with stack traces; just the log info that I'm recording myself is all I actually need in the logs.

I've tried suppressing it by registering a new error handling function in app/global.php:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    // Don't log 403s
    if ($exception instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException) {
        return;
    }

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

I've also tried wrapping the `App:abort()` in `vleAuth.authenticate()` within a `try/catch` block, but the Exception appears to have already been handled before this catch, so it hasn't helped either.

I've rerun `composer dump-autoload` to rebuild all appropriate autoloading, and have restarted the server just in case old scripts are being help in OpCache.

Can anybody tell me how I should be suppressing this stack trace?

Comment: If you've wrapped your `App::abort` call in a try/catch and the `App::error` callback is still being invoked, the most likely culprit seems to be either using the wrong namespace, or your files not being updated properly (be it due to source control, opcache or whatever else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was in returning a response from the custom error handling function rather than a null return

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    // Don't log 403s
    if ($exception instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException) {
        return Response::view('errors.403', array(), 403);
    }

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

This still displays the 403 page correctly, but overrides calling the default error handler that was generating the stack trace